# Force ansible_hostname value or check ansible target is localhost

Tags: mysql, localhost, ansible

I am trying to do some research to work around https://github.com/ANXS/mysql/issues/20

It is necessary for the mysql role to do something slightly different based on if its running against localhost. However, my ubuntu install has `/etc/hostname` as `KarthikT-OptiPlex-GX620` instead which fails the check of `ansible_hostname==localhost`. Manually setting `ansible_hostname=localhost` in the host line in my inventory file, didnt seem to help, since it doesnt seem to affect the output of `ansible localhost -m setup -i hosts/development.ini`

I know I can set my `/etc/hostname` to `localhost` to get it working, but I wonder if there is a better way, so that it might be useful to other users of this role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `inventory_hostname`. If you run your playbook on localhost (`hosts: localhost`), comparing against that should work.